# url handler windows and default browser

Tags: windows, url, browser

I've created a custom url handler in windows registry so 
that any link which begins with wxyz:// launches an application..

under shell/open/command , i discovered I could replace
the application exe path with a url - so that if 
(Default) is set to "iexplore http://mydomain.com?url=%1" and the
link wxyz://thequickbrowsnfox is clicked , the users browser
will goto http://mydomain.com?url=wxyz://thequickbrownfox

Considering, internet explorer might not be the users choice,
how can I have the page open using the users default
browser..

Answer (score 0):

I just searching for the same question and I got the answer from [Windows RegKey - Default Browser Application Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813058/windows-regkey-default-browser-application-path). However I noticed that the registry path to get default browser changed since Vista: [How Does Your Browser Know that It’s Not The Default](http://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/).

Based on the registry value, you only get the (browser) `Progid`. To get the .exe path, you need to get from `"HKCR\\<Progid>\\shell\\open\\command"` just like the answer here [Get dll directory from ProgID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10227575/186334).

My concern is what if user change the default browser after you set the url handler? Your url handler does not point to the current default browser anymore. I afraid you need to create an application to accept the url handler (not the browser itself) and find the current default browser in the registry before you launch the browser.